# Wallpaper is not seen in fullscreen

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-background

The wallpaper does not cover the screen fully. There are black background in the top as well as in the bottom, wallpaper is only in the center. All other windows opens normally apart from the wallpaper.

See screenshot below:

[image]

How to rectify this problem ?

Comment: Could you upload screenshot to https://imgur.com/ and add its link to the question.

Comment: Check Sudheer's answer below...

Comment: Sneetsher, I've uploaded the pic on imgur.com... The link is : http://imgur.com/CB9VdZb

Comment: Parto, everything was okay until last night. It changed all of a sudden when I turned on my PC today morning. I've been using kubuntu for over an year and haven't faced any such situations before.... Its the 1st time its happening.

Comment: Your desktop ratio is 5:4 - try to look for desktop wallpapers in google of these sizes and they will fit your desktop perfectly: 1280x1024, 2560x2048, 5120x4096

Comment: I was changing some of my other wallpapers and all of a sudden, it changed back to normalcy.. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto System settings -> Appearance there you can see option to zoom or scale or fill your wallpaper.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the wallpaper mode is setup to keep proportions. If the wallpaper image you have does not match the resolution of your desktop, then such black borders appear. You can try the following to make any wallpaper fullscreen:

In kubuntu, right click on desktop and select "Default desktop properties".

In the dialog that opens, on the right side, select "scaled" or "scaled and cropped" under positioning.

Comment: This thing didn't work for me.. I've the default Ubuntu wallpapers which have proper resolutions..